# как заставить отработать роутер до конца

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router

дело в том что в моем асинхронном роутере много функций и ждать пока они завершатся слишком долго для **axios** который делает запрос к роутеру

и когда **axios** не дожидается ответа от *API* то роутер выдает ошибку

```
router.post('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
 await fn1()
 await fn2()
 await fn3()
})
```

как сделать что бы все функции в любом случае завершили свою работу ?

Comment: Может, они и не запускаются? Если `fn1`  завершится с ошибкой, то `fn2` и `fn3` не вызовутся

Comment: ошибка только в случае разрыва соединения а так ее нету

Comment: Если ответ не требуется, так вынеси эти функции наружу и не жди их завершения в роутере(вызов без await).

Comment: без await тоже ошибка

Comment: примерно вот так https://pastebin.com/YtXDygX3